# How to show data in input field when select data at dropdown in Grocery Crud and Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

In Grocery Crud and Codeigniter , Basically i want to show data from one table(such as a_tbl) when select data or id_no(id_no will get from a_tbl) in dropdown then Name and current posting data will take in input field from table(such as a_tbl) , Then Designation, Dept  and Section will take in input field from three different table (such as desg_tbl, dept_tbl, sect_tbl).

[image]

How can i solve it , Please any help me

Comment: When you select an ID No. from the dropdown, you want to populate the remaining fields? If you want that, you need to use Javascript. A good library for using Javascript is jQuery for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX.
If you use jquery, you can do something like:

```
$("#field-ID_No").change(function(){
   $.ajax({
      'url':'your_controller/get_name_of_id/'+$("#field-ID_No").val(),
      'success':function(response){
         $("#field-Name").value(response);
      }
   });
});
```

Basically, when field-ID_No (the select/combobox) changed, the program will send a request to the server (for example: get_name_of_id/1). Assuming, you have "get_name_of_id" function in the controller that echo-ing a name based on given id, you will get the name as response.
(Sorry if it sounds complicated). And then, the value of field-Name should be changed with that echoed name.

For more information about AJAX and JQuery, you can read https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004276/755319

Answer (score 0):

I have done this what you want, it is really simple complete tutorial is on following link
http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1087-updated-24112012-dependent-dropdown-library/

hope you will find it helpful